# One socket or two for inter-process communication on single host

Tags: sockets

If I want to use (UDP) sockets as an inter-process communication mechanism on a single PC, are there restrictions on what I can set up due to the two endpoints having the same IP address?

I imagine that in order to have two processes `A` and `B` both listening on the same IP/port address, `SO_REUSADDR` would be necessary - correct? And even though that might conceptually allow for full duplex comms over a single socket, there are other questions I have if I try to go full duplex:

- would I end up receiving my own transmissions, and have to filter them out?
- would I be exposing myself to other processes injecting spurious or malicious data into my sockets due to the use of SO_REUSEADDR... or do I face this possibility simply by using (connectionless) UDP?
- how would things be different (in an addressing/security/restrictions sense) if I chose to use TCP instead?

I'm confident that there is a viable solution using two sockets at each end (one for `A -> B` data, one for `B ->A` data)... but is there a viable solution using a single socket at each end? Would there be any clear advantages to using one full-duplex socket per process if it is possible?

Comment: Why would you want both processes listening on the same port?!

Comment: Why wouldn't I? It's logically one connection... despite intending to use a connectionless protocol. So the question is: is it even possible, and if so, is it advisable (based on facts, not opinions)?

Comment: It's logically one connection, sure. But it also logically has two different endpoints. Why make things difficult?

Comment: I'm not trying to make things difficult... it's just that I have both local comms (interprocess) and remote comms, and on the remote side I can use a single port number at both ends, and full duplex comms across the connection. It just feels unsatisfying not to have a single channel and full duplex locally too. I'd like to know if it is possible, impossible, possible but not worth the hassle, etc. I want to be clear in my mind so that when I implement it, and someone else comes to maintain the code in 5 years, they get a clear picture of why things were done the way they were too.

Comment: You seem to be confusing one channel with one endpoint. Yes, you want one channel. Right. But that channel has to have two endpoints. So why this stuff about one port? A port is a connection endpoint. If you want things to be clear and easy to understand, do things the normal way. Don't try to get cute or strange. "*on the remote side I can use a single port number at both ends*" Who cares? It's endpoints that matter, not ports. Each end has its own endpoint, and each endpoint has a unique network identification.

Comment: Confusion? Maybe - hence the question :-) You say "yes, you want one channel". Ok, so the two channel endpoints need addresses. When they're on the same host, with one IP at both ends, then (normally? preferably? always?) the two endpoints must be distinguished by their port number... which immediately implies that you need two channels (contradiction!!) and each channel is only half-duplex, right? I'm just trying to understand what the "normal" way is - full duplex between hosts, yet 2 x half duplex within hosts? If there is a "normal" trick to achieve full duplex locally, I want to know it.

Comment: The normal way is that each end has a socket bound to a port. Each sends from its port to the other port.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104593/discussion-between-omatai-and-david-schwartz).

Answer (score 0):

The question arises from a misunderstanding. The misunderstanding arises from reading variable names like `receivePort` and `sendPort` with different values, and reading them as if they have an implicit link to the socket at the local end. This might make one (mistakenly) believe that two sockets are being used, or must be used - one for send, one for receive. This is wrong - a single socket (at each end) is all that is required.

If using variables to refer to ports on a single host, it is preferable to name them such that it is clear that one is `local` or pertaining to "this" process, and the other is `remote` or `peer` and pertains to the address of a different process, despite being on the same local host. Then it should be clearer that, like any socket, it is entirely possibly to support both send and receive from the single socket with its single port number.

In this scenario (inter-process communication on the same host necessarily using different port numbers for the single socket at each end) all the other questions (`SO_REUSEADDR`, `TCP` vs `UDP` and receiving one's own transmissions) are distractions arising from the misunderstanding.